# Debian squeeze without xorg?

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, installation

I'd like to install a small Debian server (as a template), which contains only the necessary packages. Even though I select only the ssh server and the Standard utilities at the software selection screen, after finishing install I've found some xorg packages on the installed system. (for example xserver-xorg)
Could you tell me why? Would it be the part of the Standard utilities? :o
Is there any way to exclude all of XFree/xorg packages? Or would be better to leave it?
I've tried to remove xserver-xorg and nothing prevented to do it.
But removing it, removed virtualbox-ose-guest-x11 too, but don't tried to remove other virtualbox packages, so I don't understand why was these installed...

Comment: I'd leave it installed, just change the standard run level to 2 in /etc/inittab (the line starting with `id:`).

Comment: Have you thought about makeing a "Linux from Scratch" (LFS) installation? This might give you a tighter System. Or a "Damn Small Linux" (DSL). I think it should be possible to install dpkg (debian packages) on LFS, DSL with some adaption. And fore sure you can still install from source.

Answer (score 1):

They appear to be part of the base install regardless of the tasksel package selection.  You can safely remove the xorg and virtualbox packages though.

Comment: OK, thank you! (Actually I can't understand, why the X server is a part of a minimal installation, but... I don't know, what is in a debian developer's mind... :) )

Answer (score 0):

If you are brave enough, you could prevent recommended packages from being installed adding this line to  */etc/apt/apt.conf*

```
APT::Install-Recommends "false";
```

This should reduce the number of package installed during a standard Debian setup, including the xorg ones